# macOS terminal asking for password every time I run copy command

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, copy

I'm running a bash command on mac that moves a file to private/etc/app_name/.

```sh
sudo cp my_file.cpp private/etc/app_name/
```

Every time the I want to run the bash file, the OS asks for my system password.

```
> ./run_copy.sh
Password: *******
```

Is there a way to by-pass this or configure in such way that I only have to enter the password once.

Comment: It shouldn't do it every time, only if it's been more than 15 minutes since the last use of `sudo`. You can edit `/etc/sudoers` to change this time period.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, on my Macbook, I see `/etc` directory having symlinks with the `/private/etc` directory which is owned by the `wheel` group & `root` is part of that group. So, you would need to use `sudo` to copy to that directory.

With that said on a Linux machine, you can work around this by adding your `group` to a new file in the `/etc/sudoers.d/<group-name>` path.

```
<grp-name> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I've just tried this on my mac, I could copy files onto `/private/etc` directory without entering the `sudo` password prompt.

Unfortunately, this comes up with some risks as users of your group get privileged access without entering any password prompt. You might accidentally delete important system files etc.,

A more niche approach could be to allow selectively like `<group> ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/copy-script`. This way, they can't run all scripts/commands with sudo privileges.